# How to get the data from ajax request in servlet page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, servlets

How to get the data from ajax request in servlet page. Here I'm calling the servlet by `$.ajax`.

```
var dataRequestObject= {}; 
                dataRequestObject= {Username:uname,Password:pword,Domain:domain,WindowsUser:windowsuser};

var dataRequestHeader= {}; 
                dataRequestHeader= {Username:uname,Password:pword,Domain:domain,WindowsUser:windowsuser};


    $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'http://localhost:8090/SampleServlet1/serv', //calling servlet      
            cache:false,
            header:dataRequestHeader,
            data:dataRequestObject,
            success:function(){ alert("Request Done");},
            error:function(xhr,ajaxOptions){
                alert(xhr.status + " :: " + xhr.statusText);
                } 
            });
```

I need those data and header in setvlet page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the `header` option is invalid. It needs to be `headers`. See also the [`jQuery.ajax()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

You can get the individual request headers by their name using [`HttpServletRequest#getHeader()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getHeader%28java.lang.String%29).

```
String headerUsername = request.getHeader("Username");
String headerPassword = request.getHeader("Password");
String headerDomain = request.getHeader("Domain");
String headerWindowsUser = request.getHeader("WindowsUser");
// ...
```

You can get the individual request parameters by their name using [`HttpServletRequest#getParameter()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29).

```
String paramUsername = request.getParameter("Username");
String paramPassword = request.getParameter("Password");
String paramDomain = request.getParameter("Domain");
String paramWindowsUser = request.getParameter("WindowsUser");
// ...
```

I however wonder how useful it is to duplicate the data over headers and parameters...

Comment: @BalusC: Thanks for your answer, but I'm getting null value

Comment: Did you fix the `header` option to be `headers`? To debug in the JavaScript side, use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com). To debug in the servlet side, you can get all header names by `HttpServletRequest#getHeaderNames()` and all parameter names by `HttpServletRequest#getParameterNames()`.

Comment: @BalusC: Thanks for your answer. Now I got the value

Comment: @BalusC: When I put 's' in headers, I got the request header value but null in request parameter. what to do? When I remove 's', I get request parameter value but null in header? Please help me

Comment: This should not happen. I'd suspect a bug in your own code. Just debug it. Use Firebug to debug the HTTP traffic (headers, params, body, etc).