# I couldn't get the POST value in servlet page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, servlets

I couldn't get the POST value in servlet page. my previous question related to this question.[How to get the data from ajax request in servlet page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042177/how-to-get-the-data-from-ajax-request-in-servlet-page)

I need dataRequestObject value in my servlet page.

```
 var dataRequestObject= {}; 
                dataRequestObject= {mark:Mark,subject:English,language:C language,author:john};

var dataRequestHeader= {}; 
                dataRequestHeader= {Username:uname,Password:pword,Domain:domain,WindowsUser:windowsuser};


    $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'http://localhost:8090/SampleServlet1/serv', //calling servlet      
            cache:false,
            headers:dataRequestHeader,
            data:JSON.stringify(dataRequestObject),
            success:function(){ alert("Request Done");},
            error:function(xhr,ajaxOptions){
                alert(xhr.status + " :: " + xhr.statusText);
                } 
            });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't send it as JSON string, but just as JS object. Change

```
data: JSON.stringify(dataRequestObject),
```

by

```
data: dataRequestObject,
```

and access the values in the servlet the usual way by the keys as present in JS object

```
String mark = request.getParameter("mark");
String subject = request.getParameter("subject");
String language = request.getParameter("language");
String author = request.getParameter("author");
// ...
```

---

Note that your servlet needs to run in the same domain, otherwise you hit the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). If it's actually running on the same domain, then I would not hardcode the domain in the JS code since it makes your code totally unportable. So replace

```
url: 'http://localhost:8090/SampleServlet1/serv'
```

by

```
url: '/SampleServlet1/serv'
```

or

```
url: 'serv'
```

as well.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this solution:

http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html