# Receive POST request sending JSON in jsp from javascript

Tags: javascript, java, json, ajax, jsp

I made an HTML page which has an input. I get the value through javascript, create a JSON, and I want to send it via ajax. I also have a JSP application, which runs a method in java that recieves this JSON and reads it so it can be stored in a database. The problem is that I don't know how to receive this call from ajax in my jsp application and sent it to my method in java. Can someone help me with this?

Javascript:

```
alert("I am about to POST this:\n\n" + dat);

$.ajax({
    url: '/path/to/file',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: dat,
})
.done(function() {
    console.log("success");
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
})
.always(function() {
    console.log("complete");
});
`
```

JSP:

```
'<%@ page language="java" import="connection.JsonHandler" %>
<%
String json = request.getParameter("dat");;
JsonHandler gson = new JsonHandler();
gson.ReadJson(json);
%>
```

Java:

```
package connection;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import entidades.User;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JsonHandler {
    public Gson CreateJson(String values) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        gson.toJson("Hello", System.out);
        gson.toJson(123, System.out);   
        return gson;
    }

    public void ReadJson(String json){
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type type = User.class;
        gson.fromJson(json,type);
    }
}
```

Comment: What code have you tried? You didn't post any code

Comment: Sorry, i'm really new to this so I haven't made much

Answer (score 0):

You can write a servlet, which will accept your POST request. Please refer to [I couldn't get the POST value in servlet page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068510/i-couldnt-get-the-post-value-in-servlet-page) or [How to get the data from ajax request in servlet page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042177/how-to-get-the-data-from-ajax-request-in-servlet-page)